# How do I debug a Solana program or smart contract?

Tags: solana-program, debug

Can I set breakpoints or step through a Solana program execution? Or how can I properly debug issues in a Solana program / smart contract?

Comment: please distill this to a single ask

Comment: Honestly, it is a single ask. “How do I debug a program”. It’s not his fault the answer isn’t straight forward. This should help though: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/debugging-solana-programs.html#facts